# Delete duplicate elements from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example, I have an array like this;

```
var arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10]
```

My purpose is to discard repeating elements from array and get final array like this;

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

How can this be achieved in JavaScript?

NOTE: array is not sorted, values can be arbitrary order.

Comment: You could loop over the array and copy all elements to a map.

Comment: @Devolus that's only valid for strings and numbers, you cannot use object or array as index key.

Comment: It's a solution but, is also brute force solution. Is there smarter (efficient) way of this?

Comment: Sort the array, iterate, push element to new array if not the same as last.

Comment: @UmurKontacı, if javascript is similar to java, then you have corresponding classes to primitives, like Boolean for boolean, Integer for int and so on. So it can be done this way.

Comment: @Devolus: But JavaScript is not like Java.

Comment: The most simple way today (01/2019): `[...new Set(arr)]`

Answer (score 267, accepted):

It's easier using [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var unique = arr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index === self.indexOf(elem);
})
```

Comment: how is this efficient ? Care to explain worst case run time depends on how indexOf works if it runs in linear time, then the worst case time is O(n^2)

Comment: @AbKDs please elaborate more on this

Comment: @MehmetInce it is not "efficient" at all, that runs in O(n^2)

Comment: how would you also remove both items if there are any duplicates?

Comment: Could someone expound on how this magic works? :-)

Comment: .filter() iterates over all the elements of the array and returns only those for which the callback returns true. .indexOf() returns the index of the leftmost element in the array. If there are duplicate elements, then for sure they're gonna be removed when their index is compared to the leftmost one. For more info check https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter :) @MadPhysicist

Comment: @SuperUberDuper same structure with the filter callback, just change the condition to one that is true when there are more than two elements in the array (it's another function, not sure if there's a default countElements or something like that by default in JS). Sorry if I didn't respond sooner, I must have missed the notification!

Comment: @Niccolò This is really inefficient: O(n²), compared to O(n) if you keep track of already-seen items as in Denys' answer (although I would use an ES6 Set rather than an object). This assumes the JavaScript implementation uses a hash table, which has O(1) insert/lookup time, but even if it uses a tree, which has O(log n) operations, then the total complexity would be O(n log n), which is still much better than O(n²). That was the point AbKDs was making, which your discussion of filter just confirmed.

Comment: This answer is still fine for very small lists though. It has the advantage of being very simple code, so less likely to have bugs in and less effort to read than code using using an auxillary store. It's less flexible though: it wouldn't work if you wanted to eliminate duplicates based on only a single field of items in the list, whereas the other solution would be easy to adapt to that.

Comment: hi, how if i just want to delete only 1, for example there are 3 numbers of 5 in array, so how to make it only 2 numbers of 5 ?

Comment: Clever and useful for many cases, but  it's worth noting that does not work for arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 24):

As elements are yet ordered, you don't have to build a map, there's a fast solution :

```
var newarr = [arr[0]];
for (var i=1; i<arr.length; i++) {
   if (arr[i]!=arr[i-1]) newarr.push(arr[i]);
}
```

If your array weren't sorted, you would use a map :

```
var newarr = (function(arr){
  var m = {}, newarr = []
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    var v = arr[i];
    if (!m[v]) {
      newarr.push(v);
      m[v]=true;
    }
  }
  return newarr;
})(arr);
```

**Note that this is, by far, much faster than the accepted answer.**

Comment: array is not always sorted.

Comment: Its easier than that

Making your approach a bit simpler

var m = [];   

arr.forEach( v => m[v]=true );   

var newarr = Object.keys(m);  

Easy, right?

Comment: This is a great answer. I would use an ES6 Set rather than an object though, so that the items in the list don't have to be strings. (Obviously that wasn't an option back when the answer was written.)

Comment: It's extremely fast with unordered arrays too. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome answer! ;)

Answer (score 11):

```
var arr = [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,10];

function squash(arr){
    var tmp = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(tmp.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1){
        tmp.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}

console.log(squash(arr));
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/7Utn7/

[Compatibility for indexOf on old browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 6):

you may try like this using jquery

```
 var arr = [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,10];
    var uniqueVals = [];
    $.each(arr, function(i, el){
        if($.inArray(el, uniqueVals) === -1) uniqueVals.push(el);
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Try following from [Removing duplicates from an Array(simple)](http://www.mickweb.com/javascript/arrays/removeDuplicates.html):

```
Array.prototype.removeDuplicates = function (){
  var temp=new Array();
  this.sort();
  for(i=0;i<this.length;i++){
    if(this[i]==this[i+1]) {continue}
    temp[temp.length]=this[i];
  }
  return temp;
}
```

**Edit:**

This code doesn't need sort:

```
Array.prototype.removeDuplicates = function (){
  var temp=new Array();
  label:for(i=0;i<this.length;i++){
        for(var j=0; j<temp.length;j++ ){//check duplicates
            if(temp[j]==this[i])//skip if already present 
               continue label;      
        }
        temp[temp.length] = this[i];
  }
  return temp;
 }
```

(*But not a tested code!*)

Comment: This function doesn't just remove duplicates, it also sorts. Why encumber Array's prototype with such a specific function (which wouldn't work for any type of array as most can't be directly sorted) ?

Comment: Maybe better to test for inequality and dispose the `continue`

Comment: @Matanya I am improving my answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9229645/989121

Comment: @thg435 I had simple error of `{` in first code that's why it was not working, now corrected and tested.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: sorry, it was meant as a comment to the question, not to your answer.

Comment: how to use these functions, where to pass array which needs to be sorted