# How to find whether there exists an object in json[] based on a particular field value using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I hava a json object as

```
var arr=[{"id":"1","ref":"100"},{"id":"2","ref":"200"},{"id":"3","ref":"100"}]
```

Now I have a function such that a new json object is passed ex.{"id":"4","ref":"400"},then I need to search the arr[] whether there is any object with same ref or not.If there is no element with that ref ,then I need to push to arr.If else not.How can we do this

```
var arr = [];
var obj = {"id":"4","ref":"400"};
function(obj){
    if(!arr.contains(obj.ref)) //this didn't work
    {
        arr.push(obj);
    }
}
```

How can we check this condition whether there is an object with same ref in array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if object is in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587061/how-to-determine-if-object-is-in-array)

Comment: Another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844560/check-if-object-value-exists-within-a-javascript-array-of-objects-and-if-not-add

Comment: The given array only contains 2 objects with same ref. i.e., 100.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) with the right callback.

```js
var arr = [{"id":"1","ref":"100"},{"id":"2","ref":"200"},{"id":"3","ref":"100"}],
    obj = {"id":"4","ref":"400"};


if(!arr.includes(o => o.ref === obj.ref)) {
    arr.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Note that it's ES7 feature and could not work on some [platforms](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/)

Comment: @Nina this worked..But I need to start a timercount of 5mins when an object is pushed in to arr and if the ref of that object gets updated to processed,I need to delete that object from arr..How can we do this?

Comment: @user7350714, you could as a new question, because this question needs more information than it could be asked and answered in comments of a different question.

Comment: @NinaScholz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509094/how-to-add-and-delete-an-object-in-json-array-based-on-events-cursor-observecha

Answer (score 1):

Use function [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which can be used also in ES5

```js
var arr = [{"id":"1","ref":"100"},{"id":"2","ref":"200"},{"id":"3","ref":"100"}]

var obj1 = {"id":"4","ref":"400"};
var obj2 = {"id":"5","ref":"200"};

function addSth(obj){
  if(!arr.some(function(el){return (el.ref === obj.ref)}))
  {
    arr.push(obj);
  }
}

addSth(obj1);
addSth(obj2);

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: one morething..I need to set a time interval of 5mins once we push that object and with in this interval if ref values gets updated to processed.I need to delete that object from arr.How can we do that?

Comment: See function [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Comment: @barbasan In the above if, in the arr object there already exists an object with same ref,how to delete that whole object from arr...slice?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve it. See [one related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747798/delete-duplicate-elements-from-an-array), [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will work

var arr = [{ "id": "1", "ref": "100" }, { "id": "2", "ref": "200" }, { "id": "3", "ref": "100" }]

obj = { "id": "4", "ref": "100" };

```
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {           
        if (arr[i].ref == obj.ref) {
            result = result + 1;
        }            
    }
    if (result == 0) {
        arr.push(obj);
    }
```