# How to add and delete an object in json array based on events (cursor.observeChanges)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, meteor

Iam using cursor.observechange such that when ever a record is added,it notifies on UI.
recordtype:
    `{"ref":"100","status":"inprogress"}`
I have an empty array

```
var arr=[];
```

When ever  I need to check if status is inprogress and that ref doesnt exist in any object in arr[]..If so then I need to push that to arr

```
arr.push(obj);
```

If that status is complete and if ref already exists in arr[],then I need to delete that from arr[]
Below is that i tried

```
var arr = [];
function addObject(obj){
       if(!arr.some(function(el){return (el.ref === obj.ref)}))
            {
                arr.push(obj);
            }
         else if{
                arr.slice(el);
                }

    }
    var cursor = TransactionDetails.find({ });
    cursor.observeChanges({
            added: function(id, object) {
              if (object.status == "incomplete") {   
                    addObject(object);
                    Notification.error("added");
                }
                    else if(object.status == "complete" {

                    addObject(object);
                    Notification.error("modified");

                }
       }

        });
```

But this is not working.How can we add and delete based on that conditions.Any help.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function for removing an object from the array `arr`.

It uses [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```
function removeObject(obj) {
    var index = arr.findIndex(o => o.ref === obj.ref);

    if (index !== -1) {
        arr.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Or an ES5 proposal with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
function removeObject(obj) {
    function getIndex(el, i) {
        if (el.ref === obj.ref) {
            index = i;
            return true;
        }
    }

    var index;

    if (arr.some(getIndex)) {
        arr.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```