# How to stop duplicate values in a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am using this code to read all the values from each object with the key "category":

`const listChapter = datas.map((data) => console.log(data.category))`

datas is an array of Objects, and there are 45 objects.

The problem is that when I console.log that, i have many duplicates values, you can see that below:

[console.log results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FruxG.png)

I want to have one unique value of each category. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have lots of duplicate values in the array? If so, you might want to filter out duplicates first...

Comment: What should exactly the format of `listChapter` be?

Comment: You can `map` over data to get each category into an array and then `filter` that array and remove any duplicate values, assuming you want an array of strings. [Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16747921/6304441)

Comment: lodash or underscore has functions to make unique elements (_.uniq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter duplicates from the data before you iterate through them.

```
var unique = datas.reduce(function(unique, data) {
  return unique.indexOf(data.category) === -1 ? unique.concat(data.category) : unique;
}, []);
```

Comment: It does the job. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You also can do the trick with the Set:

```
let data = ['Alfa', 'Alfa', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Beta', 'Omega', 'Psi', 'Beta', 'Omega'];

let arr = [... new Set(data)];
// Or   = Array.from(new Set(data));

console.log(arr);
```

Edit: I forgot that you have array of objects. In that case:

```
let data2 = [
  {'category': 'Alfa'},
  {'category': 'Alfa'},
  {'category': 'Beta'}
]    

let set = new Set();
data2.forEach((data) => {
  set.add(data.category);
});

let arr2 = [... set];

console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is minor improvement of [Tomek's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3965882/tomek-fiechowski) answer. (I am not able comment yet.)

```
const arr = [
  {'category': 'Alfa'},
  {'category': 'Alfa'},
  {'category': 'Beta'}
]; 

const unique = [...new Set(arr.map(item => item.category))];
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is faster, because of less iterations:

```
const listChapter = Object.keys(datas.reduce((ac, el) => {
    ac[el.category] = true
    return ac
}, {}))
```

Answer (score 0):

arr is the whole array.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i] == data.category) {
              remove item here;
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative one-liner using `filter()` (just for fun):

```
console.log(datas.filter((data, i, a) =>
        i === a.findIndex(data2 => data.category === data2.category)));
```