# In TypeScript I want distinct values from comma separated duplicate string:

Tags: angular, typescript

In TypeScript I want distinct values from comma separated duplicate string:

```
this.Proid = this.ProductIdList.map(function (e) { return e.ProductId;}).join(',');
this.Proid = "2,5,2,3,3";
```

And I need :

```
this.Proid = "2,5,3";
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16747921/5309449

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
this.ProductIdList = ["2","5","2","3","3"]
const tab = this.ProductIdList.reduce((acc, value) => {
    return !acc.includes(value) ? acc.concat(value) : acc
}, []).join(',');

console.log(tab) //"2,5,3"
```

You can do in one line too:

```
this.ProductIdList = ["2","5","2","3","3"]
const tab = this.ProductIdList.reduce((acc, value) => !acc.includes(value) ? acc.concat(value) : acc, []).join(',');

console.log(tab) //"2,5,3"
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be simply done with with ES6,

```
var input = [2,5,2,3,3];
var test = [ ...new Set(input) ].join();
```

**DEMO**

```js
var input = [2,5,2,3,3];
var test = [ ...new Set(input) ].join();
console.log(test);
```

EDIT

For ES5 and below, you can try,

```js
var input = [2,5,2,3,3];
var test = Array.from(new Set(input).values()).join();
console.log(test);
```

Comment: I have this error: "TypeError: (intermediate value).slice is not a function at tutocefano.js:7:29" with your answer? Maybe it's JsBin?

Comment: Yes I know it’s very strange... I just copy/past your code in jsbin and console log of test

Comment: check the demo above

Comment: @mickaelw -- See the [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20input%20%3D%20%5B2%2C5%2C2%2C3%2C3%5D%3B%0D%0Avar%20test%20%3D%20%5B%20...new%20Set(input)%20%5D.join()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(test)%3B) that the array destructuring statement `[ ...set ]` is compiled to, for ES5 target and below it will use `slice` to do the shallow array copy. The browser in question simply doesn't support it, and needs a polyfill.

Comment: Also, this answer will be giving a compile error on targets below ES6.

Comment: @Sajeetharan If you need ES5 and below, just use `Array.from(new Set(input).values())` instead of the `Set` directly.

Comment: Uhm I think my browser doesn't support Set directly. With Array.from that's work well