# Remove duplicates from array in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am new to typescript, and i've been having some problems in using my javascript skills. For example, **can someone help me to write this exactly same javascript code below in typescript?**

If not possible at all, any typescript function that will render the expected output (array without duplicate values).

This is just a simple way to remove duplicates from an array, but seems like typescript doesn't let me define an empty object... I'm not sure...

The output of the code below is: ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo']

Thanks!

```
const names = ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo', 'John'];

function removeDups(names) {
  let unique = {};
  names.forEach(function(i) {
    if(!unique[i]) {
      unique[i] = true;
    }
  });
  return Object.keys(unique);
}

removeDups(names)
```

Comment: all javascript is proper typescript

Comment: @frozen not when you enable the `strict` compile flag, which is the default with `tsc --init`...

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a very easy and performant way to remove duplicate elements from an array by leveraging the built-in behaviour of `Set`:

```js
/**
 * Construct a copy of an array with duplicate items removed.
 * Where duplicate items exist, only the first instance will be kept.
 */
function removeDups<T>(array: T[]): T[] {
    return [...new Set(array)];
}

const names = ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo', 'John'];
console.log(removeDups(names)); // ["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhhB7AdgZwC4CcCuBjVkCGk28ADgJ6TwBmBiB66+FA7gJaoAWkAJpiQDats+VAFNI7UQFtkkdNPgA3UdwB0UGAHUOo+Tz6DhYiWJmRRAD1ZoANJUT8KncVVbo0ElKnyJs4tvz8kABG4gDWoiSo6tDA4FSYvqisSHIKygAifMgAPAAqAHwAFPgMTABckHkA2gC6AJSVNbWQAN7gAJDyqJjodNWqg4iizJAAyqKoJWVk9bUA3OAAvuDgxF6QiPhSorIAvJDVAOQAUvAciEd2RwAK+Jj8V5BHAOKi8OgA5qJPRwBKrEQn3gvzOFyOCzWSGQ8H4olU-HgnyK8ikSlEWRIyCKWx2yHq9XmkGAwEOACIwYgyXYyXcHtTIGS3h9vgyyQCgfAybVwEA)

That function converts your array to a `Set`, which removes duplicates faster than any native loop through the array will manage, and then uses spread syntax to convert that `Set` back into a new array.

By making the `removeDups` function use a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), it can be used with any type of array, not just string arrays like your example.

---

To convert the function you have written into TypeScript, here's what you can use:

```js
const names = ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo', 'John'];

function removeDups(names: string[]): string[] {
  let unique: Record<string, boolean> = {};
  names.forEach(function(i) {
    if(!unique[i]) {
      unique[i] = true;
    }
  });
  return Object.keys(unique);
}

removeDups(names)
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCGBbAphGBeGBtA5AKRAAswcAaGHABXgFcAbMigcWRACcBzZRnAJQEswHEDwLEcAXQDcAKBkAzGmGBR+4GG2SIQAN2QARGgAcIACgQoIALhjQ2gjlgkBKG3YdOYAbxkwYdZFglfgBHGmQbXmRQNgATAB53IXIAIxAQAPgwAD4MbwBfWT8LVAA6eXYAUXhgQlNFZVVwU35nb18-GH55UwBCYLDkLH4Xds7OgfDhiTyoNnCizvyO-OdFzSgaNjAYAHkUgCtoqFKAa2QATzNJ5DWZZZlNbT1DE3MkVGcgA)

This uses the [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) `Record` for your `unique` object's type. However, due to how `Object.keys` works, this function will only be able to work on arrays of strings. If you want to use this approach with all types of array, you could consider using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead so you can index it by other types.

That would look something like this:

```js
const names = ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo', 'John'];

function removeDups<T>(names: T[]): T[] {
  let unique: Map<T, boolean> = new Map();
  names.forEach(function(i) {
    if(!unique.has(i)) {
      unique.set(i, true);
    }
  });
  return Array.from(unique.keys());
}

console.log(removeDups(names)); // ["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCGBbAphGBeGBtA5AKRAAswcAaGHABXgFcAbMigcWRACcBzZRnAJQEswHEDwLEcAXQDcAKBkAzGmGBR+4GG2SIQAN2QARGgAcIAHgAqAPgAUCFBABcMc1gkBKJy4kwA3jJgwdMiwSvwAjjTITgCy8EYW5ABGICBB8GCWGHDIAO4wsUbWbrIBdqgAdPLsAKLwwITWisqq4Nb8br7+ATD88tYAhKERyOWE8BBtbh1+3d1DkeUQwW3kUGyRxV0BAL5d25sBmlA0bGAwAIJsbPAAnpVsIIjW8yMA1sg3E1OyuzKgkKkRnQQBxrJptHpDCZbEhUN8YAB6BHYABEYjAKPIKOo9ExMBRLHYXDxKIEQhAKIkMiAA)

Answer (score 1):

```
names = ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo', 'John']; 

removeDups(names) {
 let unique = {};
  this.names.forEach((i) => {
    if(!unique[i]) {
      unique[i] = true;
    }
  });
  return Object.keys(unique);
}
```

Then call `removeDups` from where you want

Here is [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16747921/1930348):

```
names = ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo', 'John']; 

removeDups(names) {

  return this.names.filter((elem, index, self)=> {
    return index === self.indexOf(elem);
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you just have to add types

```
const names = ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo', 'John'];

function removeDups(names: string[]) {
  let unique: any = {};
  names.forEach(function(i: string) {
    if(!unique[i]) {
      unique[i] = true;
    }
  });
  return Object.keys(unique);
}

removeDups(names)
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCGBbAphGBeGBtA5AKRAAswcAaGHABXgFcAbMigcWRACcBzZRnAJQEswHEDwLEcAXQDcAKBkAzGmGBR+4GG2SIQAN2QARGgAcIACgQoIALhjQ2gjlgkBKGAG8ZMGHWSwl-AEcaZBt4MABPDHcAX1kvC1QAOnl2AFF4YEJTRWVVcFN+GzsHVw8vL355UwBCfyDkLH4Xd09yrzrgxokoqDZguPLo1ujnAc0oGjYwGAB5ACMAK2QVRIBrZHCzDuRRmSGZTW09QxNzJFRnIA)

Comment: Using `any` is bad practice, and should be avoided. Consider `any` as basically saying "Don't use TypeScript for this part".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and generic method to de-duplicate any array.

```
Js:
deDup = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, current) => {
  if(!acc.includes(current)) acc.push(current)
  return acc
}, [])

Ts:
deDup = (arr: any[]) => arr.reduce((acc, current) => {
  if(!acc.includes(current)) acc.push(current)
  return acc
}, [] as any[])
```

Since this by definition is reducing an array by removing duplicate values, call reduce being sure to pass in an initial value of a new empty array (accumulator). On each index (current) if it's not in the accumulator array then add it, then return the accumulator array. This will quickly return a new array to the caller without any duplicates.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow :) It's worth knowing that using `Array.prototype.reduce` in this way will construct a new array for each element of the initial array, so this approach will be relatively slow and memory-intensive. `reduce` is also pretty infamous for being difficult for humans to parse, compared to a loop. It works, but there are definitely better ways to reach the same outcome. The type `any` is also best avoided, because it's basically saying "Don't use TypeScript for this bit" - you lose all type safety with the `any` type.